# Python Plotting and displaying multiple objects in same GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, plot, tkinter

I have a 2 part question:

what is the best method for plotting data in Python? I only need to plot data in 2d.

I have a canvas GUI that I built using Tkinter's canvas function. It draws an 8x8 grid of rectangles and also has some code to allow you to scroll the window. (I've attached a picture).

Is it possible to include a plot in the same window as this canvas object? I need to be able to display plotted data and hopefully add buttons to my GUI that will allow me to update the plot during the run of the GUI.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is the de-facto way to plot data with Python. It's really wonderful. It can also be [embedded](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) in Tk.

Comment: Can you plot with it in real time? Like with input being read from a file? Or changing features/options with GUI buttons?

Comment: Absolutely. You can even display animations. (It's a bit tricky, though) The documentation is pretty good. Take a look at the other user interface examples: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/index.html